# Can't import multiple features or rasters into file geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, spatial-database, feature-class

I am trying to use the import multiple features into geodatabase option in ArcCatalog (ArcGIS 10.1). Or, similarly, I try to use the import raster option, which screen layout is similar to the multiple features screen, allowing you to import multiple rasters at once.

The process goes through with a green check mark, but when I expand the geodatabase, nothing is there, not if I refresh, not if I close the program and reopen.

If I use the option to import a single feature class into a geodatabase, it goes fine. That is what I have been doing as a work around. However, there is no such "import single raster" screen, so now I'm stuck as I need to import rasters.

Any ideas of what could be the problem and how to fix it?

I'm teaching a GIS course at a university, so am scratching my head about this problem, as my students are experiencing the same problem on their computers as well.

Here is the dialogue after it is finished--nothing unusual that I can note (used ~~~ to replace personal info here):
Executing: FeatureClassToGeodatabase C:\Users\~~~\Documents\ArcGIS\Data\Canada\ontario_coastline.shp;C:\Users\~~~\Documents\ArcGIS\US_coastline.shp C:\Users\~~~\Documents\ArcGIS\~~~.gdb
Start Time: Tue Oct 13 22:20:03 2015
Running script FeatureClassToGeodatabase...
Completed script FeatureClassToGeodatabase...
Succeeded at Tue Oct 13 22:20:03 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)

And this is the output from the results menu from another attempt with just one file, but using the import multiple command:

[image]

Comment: What version of arc are you on?  Are the computers current on the version service packs?

Comment: 10.1, and, yes, the service pack versions of Windows are current.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add additional details that are requested using comments.  I think you should go to Geoprocessing | Geoprocessing Options and turn off background processing as a test.  It may give you more information about what is happening.  You could also look at the Geoprocessing | Results window.

Comment: Post edited, with more info; and turning off background processing did not affect the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your issue with ArcGIS 10.3.1. Couldn't find a bug corresponding to it neither. As a workaround:

- for rasters: try the [Raster To Other Format](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000032000000) tool. Set the output workspace to your geodatabase and leave the third parameter (Raster Format) blank.
- for shapefiles: you can run [Feature Class to Feature Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Feature_Class_To_Feature_Class/001200000020000000/), or [Copy Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Copy_Features/001700000035000000/), in [batch mode](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00210000000w000000) (right-click the tool > Batch). If all the shapefiles are in the same workspace, you can also use these tools within ModelBuilder with the [Iterate Feature Classes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00400000000r000000) iterator (something useful to teach to your students anyway):

[image]

Batch and ModelBuilder can be used for rasters as well, if Raster To Other Format doesn't work for you. In ModelBuilder, use the [Iterate Rasters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Iterate_Rasters/00400000000z000000/) iterator.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. I tried the Raster to Other format tool, with no success. Some outcome, which says it worked, but didn't. I worked on the model with the raster, but don't know ModelBuilder well enough to develop the same model you did (though got part way ). I could teach this later in the semester, but at this point, just need a way to import rasters into the geodatabase that does not involve teaching them something new at the moment. The issue seems to be, whenever I pull up an import window, if it is just a single import, then it works, if multiple, it doesn't.

Comment: @Cory A. What about using the tool in Batch mode, does it work?